# Constructing fast boolean logic out of a string

Tags: python

Let's say I have a rather contrived example like:

```
X = {'a':True, 'b':False}
x = ("a","and","b")
y = ("a","or","b")

def func(z):
    return X[z[0]] 'and/or' X[z[2]]
```

Is there a fast way to construct such a logic:

1. without `eval`, because it's a significant overhead for a function evaluated in a loop ~1e6 times
2. without `if/else` logic because it again will add overhead and real logic could be lengthy?

Comment: Do you just need to understand a couple of operator names like `"and"` and `"or"`, or do you need to do a full parse of an arbitrary expression?

Comment: I think I am after the latter. I have a string as an input, and the outcome should be the statement in another function (class method). And I am counting ~100ns. And there will be no other logic than `and` or `or`

Comment: Well, it's a question of how complex your input strings are. If it's reliably of the simple form your example shows, where there are two arguments and one operator name, it's feasible - the posted answer is close to how I'd do it, I'd probably personally choose to explicitly bind the operator functions in my own dict rather than use `getattr` but that's not a big deal. But if you have nested expressions, parens, negation, etc - that's out of scope for what I personally would try to tackle.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper `How complex`. Arbitrary length. One level of nestedness at most.

Comment: Personally when I start having to worry about parsing of that kind of complexity (eg anything with nesting) I start looking for preexisting solutions. I haven't actually worked with this project so I can't specifically endorse it, but `pyparsing`  comes up as one common choice, as for instance in this example: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/simpleBool.py - but I don't know if it'll hit your performance goals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `operator` with recursion to handle arbitrary expression strings:

```
import operator
X = {'a':True, 'b':False}
def _eval(s):
   l, o = None, None
   while (n:=next(s, None)) not in {')', None}:
      if n in {'and', 'or'}:
         o = n
      else:
         v = n if n != '(' else _eval(s)
         if l is None:
            l = v
         else:
            s = iter([getattr(operator, f'{o}_')(X.get(l, l), X.get(v, v)), *s])
            l, o = None, None
   return l

import re
def run_eval(s):
   return _eval(iter(re.findall('\(|\)|\w+', s)))

print(run_eval('a and b'))
print(run_eval('a or b'))
print(run_eval('a and (b or (a and b)) or b'))
```

Output:

```
False
True
False
```

Edit: evaluating tuple-based input:

```
from collections import deque
X = {'a':True, 'b':False, 'c':True}
def _eval(t):
   d = deque(t) #using deque for faster element removal and addition
   while len(d) > 1:
      a, b, c = [d.popleft() for _ in range(3)]
      v1, v2 = X[a] if a in X else (a if not isinstance(a, tuple) else _eval(a)), X[c] if c in X else (c if not isinstance(c, tuple) else _eval(c))
      d.appendleft(getattr(operator, f'{b}_')(v1, v2))
   return d[0]

def run_eval(t):
   return _eval(t)

print(run_eval(("a", "and","b")))
print(run_eval(("a", "or","b", "or", "c")))
print(run_eval((("a","and","b"), "or",("a","and","b"))))
```

Output:

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! I need to check how speedy it is.

Comment: Thank you very much again! May I ask you to adjust your [valuable] answer to fit the input format: `("a", "and","b")` or `("a", "or","b", "or", "c")` or `(("a","and","b"), "or",("a","and,"b"))`, i.e. either tuple or iterable of tuples?  And `re` is overkill for my project...

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Definitely, please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the built-in [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) library. Something like below:

```
>>> X
{'a': True, 'b': False}
>>> mapping
{'and': <built-in function and_>}
>>> 
>>> def f(z):
...     return mapping[z[1]](X[z[0]],X[z[2]])
... 
>>> f('a and b'.split())
False
>>> f('a and a'.split())
True
>>>
```